# How to explore the content of UBoot image

Tags: u-boot

I've got a UBoot image file and I would like to explore its contents.

I tried to run `binwalk u-boot.img` and this is the output:

```
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
0             0x0             uImage header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0xB6056508, created: 2019-04-01 15:46:00, image size: 280420 bytes, Data Address: 0x80800000, Entry Point: 0x0, data CRC: 0x159289AE, OS: Firmware, CPU: ARM, image type: Firmware Image, compression type: none, image name: "U-Boot 2015.07_ZZZS00_ZZZS00_v2."
170800        0x29B30         CRC32 polynomial table, little endian
173218        0x2A4A2         bix header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x0, created: 1970-01-01 00:00:00, image size: 35914 bytes, Data Address: 0x83800100, Entry Point: 0x994A, data CRC: 0x83809F4A, image type: OS Kernel Image, compression type: none, image name: ""
179190        0x2BBF6         Unix path: /path/to/xxx0001
182572        0x2C92C         LZO compressed data
197326        0x302CE         Unix path: /path/to/miiphyutil.c
212517        0x33E25         Unix path: /path/to/cmd_nvedit.c
213945        0x343B9         Unix path: /path/to/env_common.c
219014        0x35786         Unix path: /path/to/fb_mmc.c
223547        0x3693B         Unix path: /path/to/omap_gpio.c
226263        0x373D7         Unix path: /path/to/mtdcore.c
227418        0x3785A         Unix path: /path/to/musb_core.c
232195        0x38B03         Unix path: /path/to/eth.c
236378        0x39B5A         bix header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x100, created: 1970-01-01 00:00:04, image size: 52367 bytes, Data Address: 0x8380CC8F, Entry Point: 0x83800000, data CRC: 0x5B61, image name: "[initrd[:size]] [fdt]]"
236398        0x39B6E         bix header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0x5B61, created: 2023-05-17 06:20:16, image size: 1533636201 bytes, Data Address: 0x7472645B, Entry Point: 0x3A73697A, data CRC: 0x655D5D20, image name: "]]"
240198        0x3AA46         bix header, header size: 64 bytes, header CRC: 0xA20, created: 1987-01-30 03:38:21, image size: 543975795 bytes, Data Address: 0x74207061, Entry Point: 0x72746974, data CRC: 0x696F6E20, image name: "e"
```

I also tried to run `mount -o loop u-boot.img /mnt`, but this is the error: `mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop17, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`